# UDP messages from C++ are not received by Rust

Tags: c++, boost, rust, udp

I'm creating a server / client paradigm using UDP, but the Rust server is not receiving the C++ client messages. I have been able to successfully do Rust server / Rust client and C++ server / Rust client communication.

This leads me to believe that there is an issue with my C++ code, or there is some type of miscommunication when sending C++ buffers to Rust, but I have used code that I beleive works. This is only being sent from and to the same computer and has not been expanded to computer to computer.

I am no expert with UDP / TCP so I may be doing something incorrectly

Rust server:

```rust
use std::net::UdpSocket;

fn main() {
    let udp: UdpSocket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:12000")
        .expect("Failed to bind to address for sending/receiving messages");

    udp.connect("127.0.0.1:12683")
        .expect("Failed to connect address receiving our messages");

    //The below (recv_from) is set to blocking
    let mut buf = [0; 20];
    let (number_of_bytes, src_addr) = udp.recv_from(&mut buf).expect("Didn't receive data");
    let filled_buf = &mut buf[..number_of_bytes];
    println!("{:?}", filled_buf);
}
```

C++ client:

```cpp
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
ip::udp::socket socket( io_service );
ip::udp::endpoint remote_endpoint;
std::cout << "sending reply..." << std::endl;
socket.open( ip::udp::v4() );

remote_endpoint = ip::udp::endpoint( ip::address::from_string( "127.0.0.1" ), 12000 );
unsigned char buff[8]{ 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5 };
boost::system::error_code err;
//auto sent = socket.send_to( buffer( "Jane Doe"), remote_endpoint, 0, err );
auto sent = socket.send_to( buffer( buff ), remote_endpoint, 0, err );
std::cout << err << std::endl;
std::cout << "Sent: " << sent << std::endl;
socket.close();
```

The C++ client states that the data was sent (`sent` variable) and there is no err (`err` variable). However, my Rust server never receives the data. It is set to non-blocking so it just sits there waiting to receive data (its looking at port 12000 while the client is sending to port 12000).

Comment: That `udp.connect(...)` thing in the rust code looks suspicious.

Comment: As soon as you go through a protocol like UDP, the language used to implement either end of the connection becomes irrelevant. If it implements the protocol correctly it will work, if not it won't. It doesn't matter what programming languages are used.

Comment: The documentation for [`UdpSocket`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html) has an example of using `bind` and `recv_from` — why have you decided to deviate from this?

Comment: I'm actually using the example from UdpSocket in rust. The only difference is the bind is now 0.0.0.0:12000 instead of 127.0.0.1 which i was told is better to do. I just retested using 127.0.0.1:12000 and it did not work. I'm going to look into removing udp.connect() and see what happens

Comment: @Shawn you were correct. It was the udp.connect(). I actually send a udp message (I left that out, but that's why I use udp.connect()). I created a second udp connection (that does not connect) and used that for the recv_from(...) function and it received the data!

Comment: How do you know if your sender or receiver is wrong? Maybe test the sender separately? `netcat -ul 12000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect a UDP socket, that causes the UDP socket to only receive datagrams from the address it is connected to. Servers should not connect their UDP sockets.